# Make SKU url link to product edit page in backend

Tags: magento2.3

Looking for a way to make the SKU a url to point to the product edit page in backend. Currently have a url pointing to product page in frontend for product title.

sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Fitzcode_AdminEdits::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

name.phtml

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name
 */
?>

<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
         <!-- added product url -->
        <a href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>" target="_blank"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('SKU') ?>:</span> <?= implode('<br />', $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['label'] ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['value'] ?><?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots = 'dots' . uniqid() ?>"> ...</span><span id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id = 'id' . uniqid() ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_option['remainder'] ?></span>
                            <script>
                                require(['prototype'], function() {
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').show();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseover', function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').hide();});
                                    $('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_id ?>').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){$('<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_dots ?>').show();});
                                });
                            </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way :

> create $_urlInterface object of Magento\Framework\UrlInterface

and get product edit URL help of following code in backend.

```
$this->_urlInterface->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $_item->getProductId()]);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I have edited question to show full code.